# Badges I've earned aren't always showing up in the Achievements dialog

Tags: bug, badges, notifications, achievements-dialog

Recently, I used all of my daily 40 upvotes on an SE site (Android SE). However, the achievements dialog only showed *one* of the badges - not two.

Here's a screenshot.

[image: Picture of bug]

In the screenshot, the Badges section of the website shows that I have earned the Suffrage badge a minute ago, but the achievements dialog doesn't show this - it only shows the Vox Populi badge (and the notification for that badge took about 5 minutes to show up, even with changing pages and looking at the dialog).

Both the badges should be shown in the notifications when I get them, not one of them 5 minutes later.